# Pay for Send message Apple Store

Tags: iphone, message

I have developed an application that sends messages to mobile within many more things you can do.
My question is if I go up that application that I have to pay more for an application that sends messages.
It's the same price for up an application in all cases?, I find few requirements on the rise in applications in the apple store.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about push notifications?

Apple don't charge developers to send push notifications. You pay your $99/year and 30% of your app's cost no matter what features you use.

If you're using a third party service to send out the notifications, that service might charge you, however.

Comment: Thanks Amy!, that's all. My application send text messages to mobile phone.It's simple, if you click a button you send a message from your device(mobile/tab..)